# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 2 column 1 (char 2)

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I'm trying to build a library manager of sorts, as a way to practice my programming. It uses a JSON file to store book data. The problem occurs when I try to print the full list of books stored in the JSON file, in a nice format. Here is the code:

```
import json

book = {}

def add_book():
    book['name'] = input('Enter a book name: ')
    book['author'] = input('Enter the author: ')
    with open('storage.json', 'a') as storage:
        json.dump(book, storage)
        
def list_books():
    file = open('storage.json', 'r').readlines()
    for x in file:
        book.update(json.loads(x))
list_books()
```

It gives me this error:

```
"F:\LibraryManager\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "F:/LibraryManager/database.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/LibraryManager/database.py", line 22, in <module>
    list_books()
  File "F:/LibraryManager/database.py", line 15, in list_books
    book.update(json.loads(x))
  File "F:\Python\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "F:\Python\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "F:\Python\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 2 column 1 (char 2)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is the JSON file: (storage.json)

```
{
  "name": "Lord of The Rings",
  "author": "J.R.R Tolkien"
}
{
  "name": "Harry Potter",
  "author": "J.K Rowling"
}
{
  "name": "The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn",
  "author": "Mark Twain"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd say you're doing two things wrong: 1) Trying to read non-JSON as JSON. 2) Posting this without showing your file contents.

Comment: Opening the file in append mode will concatenate the JSON objects. The result will be invalid. Parse the original, change the data and dump the data in `w` mode! Also do not use a single global dictionary for books!

Comment: Most likely your file contains single quotes `'` instead of double quotes `"`.

Comment: @KlausD. If they use `w`, then the file only contains a single object and loses all others.

Comment: @MisterNox . No it has double quotes .

Comment: That's the trick. You can parse only one object. You have to update the whole file content. Make it a list (array in JSON terms).

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON file is not correctly formatted. You have:

```
{"name": "Lord of The Rings", "author": "J.R.R Tolkien" } 
{"name": "Harry Potter", "author": "J.K Rowling" } 
{"name": "The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn", "author": "Mark Twain" }
```

You are missing commas between your lists. Try this instead:

```
{"name": "Lord of The Rings", "author": "J.R.R Tolkien"}, /* << comma here is mandatory! */
{"name": "Harry Potter", "author": "J.K Rowling"},
{"name": "The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn", "author": "Mark Twain"}
```

Since you're describing multiple objects, you must include spaces between them to tell your JSON parser that they are, in fact, separate objects.